# Combining Two Count Queries to Get Most Common

Tags: sql

I have a table for a football player grading system -

Columns are

player id - number score - decimal score

values available are

1-20 - 1-5 - 0-9

for example a player would be graded 4.9 or 3.2 etc.

I have the queries :

```
SELECT NS, COUNT(NS)
FROM playerrating
GROUP BY NS 
ORDER BY NS DESC;
```

AND

```
SELECT DS, COUNT(DS)
FROM playerrating
GROUP BY  DS 
ORDER BY DS DESC;
```

How do I combine the two to get the average score for all players ? thanks

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, not images.) BTW, do you mean football or soccer?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `COUNT()` for this ;)? And why did you split a float/double number up in two colums :( ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used my own table and column names. Please change them as you need.
Below is the SQL code:

```
SELECT Sum(avg1) FROM  
(SELECT * FROM  
(SELECT Sum(ns*nscnt)/Sum(nscnt) AS avg1 FROM   
(SELECT number_score AS ns, COUNT(number_score) AS nscnt  
FROM soccer_score  
GROUP BY number_score   
ORDER BY number_score DESC))  
UNION ALL  
(SELECT Sum(ds*dscnt)/Sum(dscnt) AS avg1 FROM  
(SELECT decimal_score AS ds, COUNT(decimal_score) AS dscnt  
FROM soccer_score  
GROUP BY  decimal_score   
ORDER BY decimal_score DESC)));
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that NS and DS are a single floating point number.

I am assuming that DS has a length of 1

I am also assuming columns are named `player_id`, `NS` and `DS` but this is not clear from your question

Then your query per player would look like:

```
SELECT player_id, AVG(NS + ( DS / 10.0 )) AS rating
FROM playerrating
GROUP BY player_id
```

For an average of all players you can use:

```
SELECT AVG(NS + ( DS / 10.0 )) AS rating
FROM playerrating
```

Comment: Thanks - poorly written question - back to the drawing board

Comment: Just give us a table of what the datatypes of the sql columns are, example data, and expected output(table) and be amazed what SO'rs can comeup with :)

Comment: playerid is INT, NS AND DS are DEC(2).  Plauerid is decending from 1 -20 (number of players) NS ranges from 1-5 and DS is 0-9.  Example data is random so each player has a score for example 2.7, 3.2, 4.6 etc etc.  I just need to build a query that can find the most common score linking two columns - in this case NS & DS in order to find the most common score for example 3.5 comes up the most therefore is the most common.  apologies for the confusion.

Comment: @JBarnard I get your question now, you are looking for the [mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_(statistics)) . This is quite difficult indeed, especially when using two columns when DS can even be 0, which can lead to `division by zero` when adding the two columns together :) there are a lot of examples on google when entering `calculate mode SQL`, see if you can find anything in there, if not, let me know and I will spent some more time on it.